# Java Switch using Maven Profile Selection

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to grab a project's maven profile that was used to compile it to use as an argument in the code as part of an if/else or switch conditional in java code?

IE:

```
switch(profileName){ 

"profile1": do this
"profile2": do that
 default: something else
}
```

etc?

Comment: We're probably going to need more context... is this code a maven plugin, or are you talking about "production" code that happens to have been built by maven?  (If the latter, there's probably a better, non-maven-specific way)

Comment: Well I have an HMI architecture that is generic. Depending on what maven profile is used to build it, it will include a module that includes the UI Screens for that type of machine and exclude others. I want to also use this within the code to define what type of machine it is instead of hardcoding something.

Comment: IIUC when this code runs it is running on _the_ type of machine it's built for, why don't you just probe the machine type instead of relying on some build configuration that's not necessarily available at runtime?

Comment: I was considering this method as a more 'dynamic' method for the following reasons: 1) We will know ahead of time. 2) We can build with only the code necessary for screens for that machine type instead of ALL screens for ALL machines. 3) Otherwise would have to hard code some way of identifying machine types by some ID (which is what we do currently and I'm seeking a better method) which may change and require the code to be changed. 4) If we are building a release using a certain profile, we will already know then what type of machine it is for.

Comment: Consider having the code use an environment variable (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), system property (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), or custom property (from a config file, for instance), and then you can use a maven profile or any other convenient mechanism to set the correct property.

Comment: That is a very good idea Gus! Thank you. If you put that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That's beyond Maven's capabilities. An alternative would be to define multiple profiles that will define your plugins and lifecycles.

Alternatively if you want to go the scripting route and be able to handle dynamic data in your build system then you could use Gradle